# Definition of dimension of a projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation, projective-geometry

The title is quite self-explanatory: I'm an undergraduate maths student who hasn't attended (yet) a course in Algebraic Geometry (but I did a course on commutative algebra), however I have to write a short essay on projective varieties for a -difficult to explain- exam.

I'm struggling with the definition of ***dimension*** of a projective variety $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n(k)$: I don't have any recommended textbook and all the material I found (which obviously doesn't involve more advanced tools like schemes) is quite confusing.

I'd be very glad if someone could spend a minute writing the correct definition (or the definitions, if there are many equivalent), and maybe where to find some material about this subject.

I apologize for this question, I know it's a bit vague, but I hope someone will be so kind as to help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you know what is the dimension of an affine variety. You don't need to know more : if $X$ is irreducible and projective, define $\dim X = \dim U$ where $U \subset X$ is an affine open. If $X$ is projective and not irreducible, define $\dim X = \sup_i \dim X_i$ where $X_i$ are the irreducible components.

Without the langage of schemes, nice references are the notes by Gathman, or the book by Harris, "A first course in algebraic geometry".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do calculations, then Nicolas Hemelsoet's answer works perfectly well. I think though that maybe the "right" definition is simply to define the Krull dimension of a topological space. Namely, the the Krull dimension of a topological space $X$ is the supremum of the length of chains $X_0\subset\dots\subset X_n$ of irreducible closed subsets of $X$. The chain that I wrote down has length $n$. You can prove now that if you have a nonempty open subset $U$ in an irreducible space $X$, then $\dim U=\dim X$. From this, you recover Nicolas Hemelsoet's definition.

Comment: Nice answer ! (+1)

Comment: I think the assertion in the penultimate sentence is untrue. Consider the Sierpinski space: it's irreducible, one-dimensional, and the generic point is a dense open zero dimensional subspace.

Comment: That sentence is true, however, if $X$ where an affine variety. I guess that's what the author had in mind.

Comment: I think $T_1$ is enough for the penultimate sentence to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another useful result in calculating the dimension of a projective scheme. Let $A_\bullet$ be a homogeneous (graded) algebra over a field $k$. Of course, we can also forget the grading and view $A$ as an ordinary algebra over the same field $k$. Then $$\dim \operatorname{Proj} A_\bullet = \dim \operatorname{Spec} A - 1.$$ For proof, see Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves* Corollary 2.5.21.

This means that we can easily calculate the dimension of projective varieties if we know how to calculate the dimension of affine varieties; we just subtract one! This lines up with the geometric intuition/most basic example that $$\dim \mathbb{A}_k^n = \dim \operatorname{Spec} k[x_1, \dotsm, x_n] =n, \; \text{and} \; \dim \mathbb{P}_k^{n-1} = \dim \operatorname{Proj} k[x_1, \dotsm, x_n] = n-1.$$

For example, consider $A_\bullet = (k[x,y,z]/(x^3-xz^2-y^2z))$ with the usual grading. The projective variety $$V=\operatorname{Proj}(k[x,y,z]/(x^3-xz^2-y^2z))$$ has dimension $$\dim V=\dim(\operatorname{Spec}(k[x,y,z]/(x^3-xz^2-y^2z))-1=3-1-1=1.$$ This dimension calculation uses:

1. $\dim(A)=\dim(\operatorname{Spec}A)$ where the dimension on the left is the Krull dimension, and the dimension on the right is the dimension as a topological space.
2. For any domain $A$ which is a finitely generated algebra over a field $k$ and ideal $I\subset A$, we have $\dim(A/I)=\dim(A)-\text{ht}(I).$
3. Krull's Hauptidealsatz: For a general commutative ring $A$ and a nonzero, noninvertible element $a\in A$, the principal ideal $I=(a)$ of $A$ has height at most 1. Moreover, $\text{ht}(I)=1$ iff $a$ is a non-zero divisor.
4. The polynomial $x^3-xz^2-y^z$ is clearly not a zero divisor of $k[x,y,z]$.

The variety $V$ is a projective nodal cubic, and this dimension calculation shows that $V$ is a curve.